# Oracle - Cant see all procedures inside a package in the 'Target:' list of Run

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, package, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a package in Oracle which has lets say 10 procedures in it. But can only see 7 out of them in the Target list of Run. Though there is no compilation error when the package is compiled.

Also the procedure is declared in the package specification.

Below screenshots demonstrate my question better.

Like in 1st screenshot i have a package named `Device` with 2 procedures. There are no compilation errors but when the green triangular Run button is clicked a window like as shown in screenshot2 opens up. In this window the Target panel on the top left only lists just 1 procedure and not both of them.

[image]

Screenshot1

[image]

Screenshot2

How to view all the procedures of the package in Target?
What could be the possible reason as to why its not in the Target list?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is a Target list? Is this specific to some desktop tool? A working demo would be helpful.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the code for the package specification and package body; and what you are doing to try to generate this "target" list.

Comment: `@William Robertson`, `@MT0` Please check my edited question.

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue when running the PL/SQL from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=967c017f16cc3cc2ca02ea6c0fddb6f8). Can you get the procedure to work by calling it from a script in the console (without going through the "Run" dialog)?

Comment: Also, don't @ mention people inside a `code block` as it doesn't notify them of the reply.

Comment: What version of SQL Developer are you using?

Comment: From your screenshot, It is very much clear that you are reffering to different package. Screenshot of code shows that package name is `device`. While screenshot of execute window shows that you are executing `device_ok_nok` package.

Comment: `Popeye` Edited question by replacing with correct screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The procedures need to be declared in the package specification in order to be executed outside of the package. See this [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bb939489aaac10735e53260d08a3024e) for a demo.

Not declaring the procedure in the package specification can be done intentionally so some procedures should only be executed from inside the package.

Comment: `@Andrew Sayer` The procedure is already declared in the package specification. I edited my question as well. Then why is it still not listed in Target? Also, a peer having same setup as mine machine's is able to view it in their environment.

Comment: What client are you using to view this list of procedures? What happens when you `desc` the package?

Comment: `@Andrew Sayer` `desc` doesnt list the package. I have oracle 12c.

Comment: The `desc` command takes the package name as input and lists out what's specified by it. eg `desc device`. Oracle12c is not a client, your screenshots look like SQL Developer. Which version of SQL Developer are you using? I cannot replicate your problem on the latest one available, do you still have the issue after you update to the latest?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem today.in my case i have 4 procedures in my package in which 3 procedures have input parameters and 1 is not having input parameter and out parameters.in my target it showed only 3 procedures which has in/out parameters.
when i added in parameter for the procedure which is not listed in target after refresh all 4 procedures listed in the target
this may help